# Caffe Element-Wise multiplication with fixed blobs

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, elementwise-operations

I think I will be asking multiple quesitons here, I'd love any comment because I'm new to Caffe.

In my network input images have size `1x41x41` Since I am using 64 batch size I think the data size will be `64x1x41x41` (Please correct me if this is wrong)

After some convolutional layers (that don't change the data size), I would like to multiply the resulting data with predefined blobs of size `1x41x41`. It seems convenient to use `EltwiseLayer` to do the multiplication. So in order to define second bottom layer of the `Eltwise` I need to have another input data for the blobs. (Please advise if this can be done in other way)

The first question: Batch training confuses me. If I want to multiply a batch of images with a single blob in an `EltwiseLayer` should the bottom sizes be the same? In other words should I use `repmat` (matlab) to clone 64 blobs to have a size of `64x1x41x41` or can I just plug single blob of size `1x1x41x41`?

Second question: I want to multiply the data with 100 different blobs and then take the mean of 100 results. Do I need to define 100 `EltwiseLayers` to do the job? Or can I collect blobs in a single data of size `1x100x41x41` (or `64x100x41x41`) and clone the data to be multipled 100 times? And if so how can I do it? An example would be very useful. (I've seen a `TileLayer` somewhere but the info is spread across the galaxy.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use tile layer instead of repmat

Comment: what's the point of multiplying 100 times with **fixed** matrices and then taking the mean? Take the mean of the 100 matrices **once** and multiply by the blob

Comment: @Shai You're actually right about taking the mean of blobs. I am not sure how I will merge 100 results, maybe I can use maxpooling etc. For the tile layer [link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4422) was unable to answer how was I supposed to use it; and I also cannot follow doxygen documentation to understand which parameters to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do element-wise multiplication in caffe both blobs must have **exactly** the same shape. Caffe does not ["broadcast"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) along singleton dimensions.
So, if you want to multiply a batch of 64 blobs of shape `1x41x41` each, you'll have to provide two `64x1x41x41` bottom blobs.
As you already noted, you can use [`"Tile"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/tile.html) layer to do the `repmat`ing:

```
layer {
  name: "repmat"
  type: "Tile"
  bottom: "const_1x1x41x41_blob"
  top: "const_64x1x41x41_blob"
  tile_param {
    axis = 0   # you want to "repmat" along the first axis
    tiles = 64 # you want 64 repetitions
  }
}
```

Now you can do `"Eltwise"` multiplication

```
layer {
  name: "mul"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "const_64x1x41x41_blob"
  bottom: "other_blob"
  top: "mul"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: MUL
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use operation: PROD, not operation: MUL
https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/eltwise.html